# add future date to a date gotten from json response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a date gotten from json response. I able to filter the date to confirm that it is actual date type but I am not able to set future date to it. Below is my snippet

```
$rootScope.until= response.data.data.dateReceived;

//return future date
// var targetDate = new Date();
$rootScope.until.setDate($rootScope.until + 60);//adding 60 days but cannot


// So you can see the date we have created
$rootScope.until = $filter("date") ($rootScope.until), 'EEEE, MMMM d, y');
```

Please how can I add future dates

Comment: The date you've gotten from your JSON data — what format is it? Milliseconds? ISO-8601 timestamp?

Comment: this is the date >>> 40508623308 in milliseconds

Comment: Is this supposed to be a date in the year 1971? If not, I don't know what format you're using. Understanding the form of your input data is critical to solving any problem.

Comment: yes it is in 1971 in milisecond format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two different mistakes here.

1. You're trying to use `Date` functions on a `Number`.
2. The function `Date#setDate()` takes as its argument the *day of a
   month*, not the timestamp itself.

---

## Date vs. Number

#### Problem

If you used `new Date(response.data.data.dateReceived)` to convert the number of milliseconds you received into a `Date` datatype, you would be able to access methods like `setDate()`.

However, with your current code, you're trying to perform `setDate()` on what — to JavaScript — is just an ordinary number. It might as well be `-1`, since JavaScript has no idea that your number means anything more than its numeric value.

#### Solution

Since your input data is in milliseconds (a fact you indicated in the comments), the easiest way to accomplish this would simply be to add milliseconds to your initial timestamp like so:

```js
const SIXTY_DAYS = 5184e6; //1000ms/sec * 3600secs/hour * 24hours/day * 60days
$rootScope.until= response.data.data.dateReceived + SIXTY_DAYS;
```

Just make sure that the value is a number, not a string, otherwise this will perform concatenation instead of addition.

---

## setDate arguments

#### Problem

If you *do* have a variable with a datatype of `Date` (see above), you *would* have access to methods like [`Date.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate). However, this method's arguments are a bit different than what your code assumes.

#### Solution

`setDate()` takes in as its argument a number of **days** since the start of the month. If you want to add a number of days, you could do the following:

```js
$rootScope.until= new Date(response.data.data.dateReceived);
$rootScope.until.setDate($rootScope.until.getDate() + 60);
```

This code will obtain the *day of the month* for the date, then add 60 days to that value. It will automatically handle the change in the month.

Comment: @Float You should just be able to use an AngularJS date filter like so: `$filter('date')($rootScope.until, 'EEEE, MMMM d, y');`